# Deducting lives on Cocos2D

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Say If I had an apple falling from the top of the screen and the player needs to catch it before it is gone of the screen at the bottom. I want to give the player 3 (Lives) chances to catch the apple. Each time the object reaches the bottom of the screen the lives should go -1.

```
Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple2.png"];
Apple.position = ccp(250,768);
[self addChild:Apple];
```

This is where the apple sprite created above gets updated until it reaches the bottom of the screen:

```
-(void) callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt
{
    Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y -200*dt);
    if (Apple.position.y < -100+64)
    {
        Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, 768);
    }
}
```

The if statement is just for testing to make the apple fall again if it is missed.

Any help would be appreciated!, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an integer inside `@interface` as u did for your CCSpirte `Apple` like this

```
@interface NameOfMyClass : CCScene {

    int myLife;

}
```

set myLife to 3, `myLife = 3;` in your init method, then inside `-(void) callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt`

```
if (Apple.position.y < -100+64)
{
    Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, 768);
    myLife--; 
}

if (myLife == 0) 
{
     //GAME_OVER
}
```